# Contacting instagram Developer

Tags: submit, instagram, sandbox, live, instagram-api

I am currently testing a site/portal. Our site aims to grant users access to their own pictures on instagram.

Our codes work effectively in the sense that we are able to do that in sandbox mode. However, instagram has declined our approval to switch from sandbox to live..giving reasons that were not so clear
*"The use case described in your submission notes, screencast and website is not a valid use case that we allow on our Platform"*
..and pretty much no opportunity to resubmit.

Is there anyway to contact instagram? Or how does it work? Do I make another sandbox invite and hope I got it right?
Any advice will be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The official Instagram support email is support@instagram.com. Also, if you would like to contact them via another channel, you can do that from the Instagram app (gear wheel) in your profile, as the following image (Android app version).

[image: Android Instagram App]

Besides that, I would recommend you read carefully the documentation again, once they've been changing it often.

Here are some useful links to read:

- [API Terms of Use](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/)
- [Brand Guidelines](https://en.instagram-brand.com/)
- [Permission Review Documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/)

I hope this helps and you have the chance again to publish the app. :)